# Ignoring platform 'android-2': build.prop is missing

Tags: android, build, android-sdk-tools

I created a new project and new workspace in Eclipse (on Windows 7).
When I start Eclipse I get this warning in the console:

```
[2014-03-04 18:59:11 - Android SDK] Warning when loading the SDK:

Warning: Ignoring platform 'android-2': build.prop is missing.
```

The compiler shows an error:

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to turn off Comodo Internet Security.

Or to add

`android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.2\aapt.exe`

`android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`

to a list of trusted files for Comodo Defense+.